# "will" and "be going to", which is correct to express this situation?

Tags: future

I'm wondering which one of "will" and "be going to" is more appropriate to mention the event which seems to definitely happen without fail in the future?
For example:

1. He is going to be 10 years old next month.
2. He will be 10 years old next month.

Comment: There’s no difference in meaning in those two sentences.

Comment: In speech they’d be more likely to stated as: “He’s gonna be 10 years old next month” and “He’ll be 10 years old next month.”

Comment: He will be 10 years old next month is the right